# Laravel & PHP: Return special formatted JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel

After doing a query, how can I **create** and **echo** a formatted JSON like this:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "user_id": "1",
      "name": "Apple",
      "address": "7538 N LA CHOLLA BLVD",
      "city": "Palo Alto",
      "state": "CA",
      "latlon": [
        -111.012654,
        32.339807
      ],
    },
    {
      "user_id": "2",
      "name": "Microsoft",
      "address": "75 S BWY STE 400",
      "city": "Palo Alto",
      "state": "CA",
      "latlon": [
        -73.764497,
        41.031858
      ],
    },
   ],

  "meta": {
    "page": 1,
    "per_page": 10,
    "count": 493,
    "total_pages": 50
  }
}
```

This is my current query:

```
public function getAgenciesJson() {

    $agencies = DB::table('users')->where('type','a')->orWhere('type','l');

}
```

Haven't figured out how to output JSON like that, considering I have a "latlon" field like [-111.012654,32.339807], also a "results" tag and a "meta" tag.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I downvoted all answers that do not take into account your request to pre-format the json to use "results" and "meta". Seems like noone reads questions properly nowadays. @espadav8 has a good solution using a transformer (or presenter).

Comment: Just curious why you're using `DB::table('users')` instead of accessing the table via the model `Users::where('type', 'a')->orWhere('type', 'l')`.

Answer (score 3):

What you need is something called a transformer (or presenter) to convert your raw model into a format that can be sent to your users.

A very popular package is called Fractal (http://fractal.thephpleague.com/) by Phil Sturgeon. There's a Laravel package, that might make it a bit easier to use, called Larasponse (https://github.com/salebab/larasponse).

Phil actually a blog post about this just the other day - https://philsturgeon.uk/api/2015/05/30/serializing-api-output/ - that goes into why you should always have some kind of transformer between your models and what you send to your users.

There's also a guide about using Larasponse and Fractal that might be of use here - http://laravelista.com/laravel-fractal/.

The gist of it boils down to passing the model through another class that will take the models values and build an array/object in a known/fixed format, e.g. (from Phil's blog post)

```
return [
    'id'      => (int) $book->id,
    'title'   => $book->title,
    'year'    => (int) $book->yr,
    'author'  => [
        'name'  => $book->author_name,
        'email' => $book->author_email,
    ],
    'links'   => [
        [
            'rel' => 'self',
            'uri' => '/books/'.$book->id,
        ]
    ]
];
```

This way you're not exposing your original field names and if at any point your column names should change you only need to update that in 1 place rather than having to get any user of your JSON to update their site/app. It will also allow you to do string manipulation of your latlon column so that you can split it into 2 different values.

Using a slightly modified example from the Fractal documentation. Say you have a transformer for a User

```
class UserTransformer extends Fractal\TransformerAbstract
{
    public function transform(User $user) 
    {
        return [
            'id' => (int) $user->id,
            'name' => $user->first_name . ' ' . $user->last_name,
        ];
    }
}
```

You can then use this class to either transform a single item of a collection

```
$user = User::find(1);
$resource = new Fractal\Resource\Item($user, new UserTransformer);

// Or transform a collection
// $users = User::all();
// $resource = new Fractal\Resource\Collection($users, new UserTransformer);

// Use a manager to convert the data into an array or json
$json = (new League\Fractal\Manager)->createData($resource)->toJson();
```

Fractal includes a paginator adapter for Laravel that can be used straight away

```
$paginator = User::paginate();
$users = $paginator->getCollection();

$resource = new Collection($users, new UserTransformer);
$resource->setPaginator(new IlluminatePaginatorAdapter($paginator));
```

Comment: Please add additional information how to use a transformer in collaboration with a collection instead of only one model instance, include the meta as requested by TS. Great answer by the way.

Comment: How much information about the collection/meta would be good? The documentation for Fractal explains it all and adding to the answer would mostly just be copying that (is that okay?).

Comment: Linking is worse, because remote sources might change. Also you can adapt the code to fit the parameters/objects from the question.

Answer (score 1):

The method exists:

->toJson()

REF: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#converting-to-arrays-or-json

Update your getAgenciesJson to :

```
public function getAgenciesJson() {

    return DB::table('users')->where('type','a')->orWhere('type','l')->toJson();

}
```

Then you could echo by:

```
<?= SomeModel::getAgenciesJson(); ?>
```

To modify the column names you can update your select. Here is an example taken from the Laravel Docs:

```
$users = DB::table('users')->select('name as user_name')->get();
```

Here would be a more fully realized version of what you are looking for minus the column aliases since you didn't really mention what they were.

```
public function getAgenciesJson($page, $per_page = 10) {
   $output = [
        'results' => [],
        'meta'    => [],
    ];

    // Get Results
    $output['results'] = DB::table('users')->where('type','a')->orWhere('type','l')->take($per_page)->skip($per_page * ($page - 1))->get();

    // Set Meta
    $output['meta'] = [
        'page'        => $page,
        'per_page'    => $per_page,
        'count'       => DB::select('SELECT FOUND_ROWS()'),
        'total_pages' => DB::table('users')->count() / $per_page        
    ];

    // Return
    return json_encode($output);
}
```

Your original code didn't attempt to get or handle the pagination information but this example covers that in order to provide the meta data you indicated you wanted returned.

Not sure if you wanted Count to be the number of the current result set or a count of all the records on that table. If you don't want the current set you but rather the entire count you can use DB::table('users')->count() though I would assign it to a variable and use that rather than calling it twice in the meta info.

Comment: Thank you, but is there any way I can specify the fields name so they are not the same as in my table and people can't see how they're called or simply for customize the process. Also what about the "latlon" field looks like an array but on my table I have it like a plain string like "1.5435345,6.143244", also the "meta" field.

Comment: See my latest edit for selecting column names as an alias. Your latlon should be coming through as a string, it is possible whatever you used to parse your test data malformed it. Try echoing it with the mods above.

Comment: Updated to accommodate the json format using results and meta. You can update the results query with that ->select('column_name as alias_name') that I mentioned before.

Answer (score -1):

```
public function getAgenciesJson() {

    $agencies = DB::table('users')->where('type','a')->orWhere('type','l')->get();
    return response()->tojson($agencies,200);//for response with status code 200
}
```

You should call get function to get data in array format and response function will format your output to json. Second paramater signifies which status code you have to assign for your response.